# In a SELECT statement, convert column value to int, otherwise make it null

Tags: sql, sql-server

The data looks like this: 
[image: ver]

All the columns are char types.
I want to write a SELECT that converts [column 3] to INT if it's convertable:

```
SELECT TOP (100) CONVERT(INT,[Column 3])
FROM [AirportFlights].[dbo].[airport-codes_csv]
```

but the convert blows up when the contents of [Column 3] is not convertable.

> Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>       Conversion failed when converting the varchar value ' Ahus"' to data type int.

Comment: See [TRY_CONVERT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: What's the expected result for the Ahus row?

Comment: You should be aware of the fact that you are selecting 100 arbitrary rows. Using `top x` without `order by` is a mistake.

Comment: Also, if you're working with a version that's before 2012, you should consider upgrading, since that's the earliest version still supported (2008 and 2008 r2 are out of extended support since July 2019)

Comment: @ZoharPeled It's not a mistake when the user understands the effect

Comment: @nicomp true, though in my experience most of the times when you understand the effect you avoid it :-)

Comment: Thanks, @HoneyBadger !

Comment: In my experience, the number of people who know that the returned result rows are *arbitrary* (not random) are vastly dwarfed by the number of people who "know" that it returns the rows in (take your pick whether they say "an internal order", "physical order", "clustered index order" or "primary key order". I've heard all of these and they're all wrong)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's as simple as:

```
SELECT TOP (100) TRY_CONVERT(INT,[Column 3])
FROM [AirportFlights].[dbo].[airport-codes_csv]
```

Other tips i'd offer:

- As per Zohar's comment, you should always order by something if you're requesting TOP anything
- Using column names with spaces requires them to always be wrapped in [ ] - I generally avoid column names with spaces to avoid it looking messy in SQL script and avoid them being replaced with other characters by ORMs which can break naming conventions in client side code
- Consider always aliasing tables, though the reasons for doing do are very much less important when you're genuinely only working with one table, no joins

Answer (score 2):

Try may be it will helpful

```
 select top (100) convert(int, case when [Column3] like '%[^0-9]%' then null else [Column3]  end)as [Column 3]
from [AirportFlights].[dbo].[airport-codes_csv]
```

Comment: yes, if you are forced to work with unsupported versions (anything below 2012)

Comment: @HoneyBadger, Thanks for your suggestion. Now i have updated my answer